# Change backend authenficiation just for a view and an app

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I would like to change the authentification backend just for the view in my api app in django ...

For the moment it's working but i have this warning :

```
You have multiple authentication backends configured and therefore must provide the `backend` argument or set the `backend` attribute on the user.
```

How to specify just one auth back just for this view ?

My version of django is 1.10.3

here is the backend auth part of my setting :

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'social.backends.facebook.Facebook2OAuth2',
    'social.backends.facebook.Facebook2AppOAuth2',
    'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'social.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
    'social.backends.email.EmailAuth',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'kewe.auth.EmailBackend',
)
```

thanks and regards

Comment: Edit Q to add your settings.py

Comment: @AbijithMg i would like to not touch my settings just choose one of the backend in the view of my app but i will edit